# Crystal Report sum by column

Tags: crystal-reports

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gHBM.png)
This is the problem with my crystal report, I need to sum values from different columns with the same name.

Comment: little information to go on

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula for each material that, depending on what position it is, returns the value for it. 
For example, 1210P_Kg could follow the logic of:

```
IF {Material 1} = "1210P" Then {Material 1_Kg}
Else IF {Material 2} = "1210P" Then {Material 2_Kg}
Else IF {Material 3] = "1210P" Then {Material 3_Kg}
```

Then, show the sum of each of these formulas in a footer section.

A more powerful solution would be to use a UNION view, command, or SP to turn each record into 3 records with Material, Kg, etc.